# How can I simply article labels? I'm reusing the same 10 lines of code, with the only difference being the label color

Tags: html, css

I am designing a basic news-ish blog. Let's say on my news blog I have about 10 categories, and each of those categories will have a label that will appear to the top right of the card image. Now each label will have it's own specific identifying color. So for example, the video label will be red, the lifestyle label will be green, programming will be orange... etc.

The code I have on the bottom works, but my problem with it is that it is reusing the same 10 lines of css, with the only changing factor being the label color.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
.article-tag-news{
    ...
    background-color: #ff8fd2;
    ...
}

.article-tag-games{
    ...
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    ...
}

.article-tag-videos{
    ...
    background-color: #123456;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a general class for the main css for the labels `.article-tag` and add the color with an new class tag `.news` etc.

```
.article-tag{
  ... //all the css applied to all the tags
}

.news{ //or .article-tag.news depending on your code 
  background-color: red;
}
```

And in your HTML use

```
<label class="article-tag news"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help1

Answer (score 3):

You can use a class for all tagged articles:

```
.article-tag-all{ 
 ...
 }

.article-tag-news{ 
background-color: #ff8fd2; 
 }
```

And use it like:

```
<article class="article-tag-all article-tag-news"></article>
```

Note: I am on my phone right now, formatting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While keeping your current markup, styles common to all articles can be grouped in a rule with an attribute selector like:

```
[class="article-tag-"] {
  /* common styles */
}

.article-tag-particular {
  background-color: salmon;
}
```

My 2¢: problem with `<label class="article-tag news"></label>` is that from now you can't style the `.news` class anywhere else OR you can't style it independently/must always style `.something-something.news {}`.